# Find best interpolation nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, scipy

I am studying physics and ran into a really interesting problem. I'm not an expert on programming so please take this into account while reading this.
I really hope that someone can help me with this problem because I struggle with this matter for about 2 months now and don't see any success.

### So here is my Problem:

I got a bunch of data sets (more than 2 less than 20) from numerical calculations. The set is given by x against measurement values. I have a set of sensors and want to find the best positions x for my sensors such that the integral of the interpolation comes as close as possible to the integral of the numerical data set.

As this sounds like a typical mathematical problem I started to look for some theorems but I did not find anything.
So I started to write a python program based on the SLSQP minimizer. I chose this because it can handle bounds and constraints. (Note there is always a sensor at 0 and one at 1)

Constraints: the sensor array must stay sorted all the time such that x_i   smaller than x_i+1 and the interval of x is normalized to [0,1].

---

Before doing an overall optimization I started to look for good starting points and searched for maximums, minimums and linear areas of my given data sets. But an optimization over 40 values turned out to deliver bad results.

In my second try I started to search for these points and defined certain areas. So I optimized each area with 1 to 40 sensors. Then I compared the results and decided which area is worth putting more sensors in. I the last step I wanted to do an overall optimization again. But these idea didn't seem to be the proper solution, too, because the optimization had convergence problem as well.

The big problem was, that my optimizer broke the boundaries. I covered this by interrupting the optimization, because once this boundaries were broken the result was not correct in the end. If this happens I reset my initial setup and a homogeneous distribution. After this there are normally no violence of boundaries but the results seems to be a homogeneous distribution, too, often this is obviously not the perfect distribution.

---

As my algorithm works for simple examples and dies for more complex data I think there is a general problem and not just some error in my coding. Does anyone have an idea how to move on or knows some theoretical stuff about this matter?

[image]

The attached plot show the areas in different colors. The function is shown at the bottom and the sensor positions are represented as dots. Dots at value y=1 are from the optimization with one sensors 2 represents the results of optimization with 2 variables. So as the program reaches higher sensor numbers the whole thing gets more and more homogeneous.

It is easy to see that if n is the number of sensors and n goes to infinity you have a total homogeneous distribution. But as far as I see this this should not happen for just 10 sensors.